# Returning FILE*

Tags: c, file-io, return

Why does this code produce the warning?

```
FILE* my_open_file(char* filename)
{
  FILE* fp=fopen(filename,"r");
  if(fp==NULL)
    {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return -1;
    }
  return fp;
}
```

- asdf.c: In function ‘my_open_file’:
- asdf.c:9: warning: return makes
  pointer from integer without a cast

fp is already a pointer, and not integer as far as I can see.

Comment: fp is a pointer, but -1 isn't. Return fp in both cases, instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler doesn't like `return -1`, which is of type `int`—but `my_open_file` is supposed to return pointer-to-`FILE`.

Use `return NULL;` to signal error.

Comment: Or just a single `return fp;` since `fp` is known to be NULL.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this warning point to return -1

Instead of it just use "return NULL"

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you want to return a pointer in any case, because your function is declared to return a `FILE *`.  So, you should return `NULL` if `fopen()` fails, and the return value of `fopen()` if it doesn't.

But then, your function is (almost) equivalent to `fopen()`!  In other words, you can replace your function by:

```
FILE* my_open_file(char* filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename);
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", filename);
        perror(NULL);
    }
    return fp;
}
```

`fopen()` isn't guaranteed to set `errno`, so I added a `fprintf()` call with the filename in addition to the `perror()` call.  Also, it's a good idea to print the filename in your error messages about failing to open a file.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning -1 on error, which then must be implicitly cast to a FILE*